# Antlr3 Non-recursive / leftfactorized grammar for expressions with a nice AST

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have defined the following production rules for expressions. The grammar is not allowed to have backtracking and k better or equal to 3. The current version seams to have some ambiguity, but I can't figure out where. I've removed the AST rules here, but the grammar is supposed to create a nice AST where operations are presented according to their priority as well as showing the left associativity of operations.

Antlr 3.2.1 with Antlerworks 1.5.1

```
disjunctionExpresion
    :   (conjunctionExpresion Disjunction conjunctionExpresion disjunctionExpresionDash) | conjunctionExpresion;

disjunctionExpresionDash
    :   (Disjunction conjunctionExpresion disjunctionExpresionDash) |;

conjunctionExpresion
    :   (relationalExpresion Conjunction relationalExpresion conjunctionExpresionDash) | relationalExpresion;

conjunctionExpresionDash
    :   (Conjunction relationalExpresion conjunctionExpresionDash)|;
    
relationalExpresion
    :   (addExpresion RelationalOperator addExpresion relationalExpresionDash) | addExpresion;

relationalExpresionDash
    :   (RelationalOperator addExpresion relationalExpresionDash)|;

addExpresion
    :   (multiExpresion addOperator multiExpresion addExpresionDash)| multiExpresion;
    
addExpresionDash
    :   (addOperator multiExpresion addExpresionDash)|;

multiExpresion
    :   (unaryExpresion MultiOperator unaryExpresion multiExpresionDash) | unaryExpresion;

multiExpresionDash
    :   (MultiOperator unaryExpresion multiExpresionDash) | ;   

unaryExpresion 
    :   (unaryOperator basicExpr)->^(unaryOperator basicExpr) | basicExpr -> basicExpr;

basicExpr
    :   Number | var basicExprDash  | ('(' expr ')')->expr;

basicExprDash
    :   'touches' var | ;
```

Comment: This grammar has mutual left-recursion. So, likely no value of k will suffice. And, it is very hard to read and incomplete. I would recommend that you enumerate the operators with precedence and associativity, and engineer a grammar using EBNF, not BNF. Follow how it is done with Java (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java8/Java8Parser.g4#L1170) or XPath (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/xpath/xpath31/XPath31.g4#L17). And, I would recommend Antlr4. If you need an AST, use action rules to synthesize one, or a bottom-up walker of the CST to construct an AST.

Comment: @kaby76 Great points and thanks but sadly that's the point of the assignment I guess. We must use Antlr3 for a top-down parser. Antlr4 autoresolves left-recursion, for what I can tell, so I can't use the recommended grammars like java8 as they are left-recursive in Antlr3. That's what the star rules are therefor to eliminate the left-recursion by hand. (Tldr I would pref Antlr4 too and not have to use AntlerWorks which is buggy af)

Comment: To break mutual recursion, draw a graph of the symbols, where an edge goes from a LHS symbol to RHS symbol. Pick the symbol with the greatest out edges, and unfold that production into all remaining rules the use that symbol. Repeat until you remove mutual recursion. Use Antlr4 only to detect the mutual recursion, but use Antlr3 for your code gen.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say to look for the cycle in that constructed graph, and pick a node with greatest out degree *that participates in the cycle*. You can actually unfold any of the productions to help break the cycle, though.

Comment: @kaby76 that sounds similar to the methode our prof thought us. I found a sexier solution with EBNF, which you've recommended :) I'll share it once I am done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @kaby76's hint of using EBNF and looking up example grammars, I have ended up with something similar to this [C++ Antlr3 example](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v3/blob/01a832dbcc8435ed0b0b56ca35c4a4a3696bb485/cpp/CPP_grammar_.g#L1808). The [Antrl3 Documentations](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687234/ANTLR+v3+documentation) for [Tree construction](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687090/Tree+construction) was also very helpful.

The "^" quick operator allowed me to create the desired AST.

```
expr    :   disjunctionExpression;

disjunctionExpression
    :   conjunctionExpression (Disjunction^ conjunctionExpression)*;

/*equal to:
disjunctionExpression
    :   (a=conjunctionExpression->$a) (o=Disjunction b=conjunctionExpression -> ^($o $disjunctionExpression $b) )*;
    
*/
conjunctionExpression
    :   relationalExpression (Conjunction^ relationalExpression)*;

relationalExpression
    :   additiveExpression (relationalOperator^ additiveExpression)*;

additiveExpression
    :   multiExpression (addOperator^ multiExpression)*;

multiExpression
    :   unaryExpression (multiOperator^ unaryExpression)*;

unaryExpression
    :   (unaryOperator^)? basicExpr;

basicExpr
:   Number | var ('touches'^ var)? | '(' expr ')' -> expr;
```

Which is actually the compact version of what I had before:

```
expr    :   disjunctionExpresion;

disjunctionExpresion
    :   conjunctionExpresion disjunctionExpresionDash;

disjunctionExpresionDash
    :   (Disjunction conjunctionExpresion disjunctionExpresionDash) |;
```